# How can i send a object from Asp.net MVC controller to Asp.Net WebForm without using Session?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Actually i want to send a object from controller action to webform load method.
I don't like to use Session or QueryString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to use some object that you create in the MVC request in a later Webforms request. 

In addition to using a Session variable or the QueryString, you can also store the object data in a cookie and retrieve it in the WebForm. 
Each of the options has its advantages:

- Session-variable: Object can be stored as is, no need to reload, e.g. from database. Decreases scalability because server memory is used per user.
- Query String: data is visible, only viable for short strings.
- Cookie: data is stored on the client and can be tampered with. Transferred between server and client several times. Size restrictions apply. Cookies might be disabled.

**Handling a huge amount of data**:

In the comments you mention that the data is huge. Therefore, I'd suggest to store the data once it is generated on the MVC part, e.g. in the database (or even the file system) and just transfer the id that is needed to retrieve the data on the Webforms end via one of the methods above. You might also need to erase the prepared data once they have been used or after some time in order to clean up left-over data.

**Recreating the data in the Webform**:

If you do not want to store the data in some kind of cache (database, file, server cache) and if you can recreate the data in the Webforms request (obviously you are able to create the huge amount of data in the MVC request), you can also choose to transfer only that bit of data to the Webform that is required to recreate the data. Bad in sense of performance, but good in that the user is always presented up-to-date information and you don't have to clean the cache if the data is not needed anymore.
In order to be able to share the functionality to create the data between the MVC controller and the Webform, you should move that to a dedicated class that is used in both web front ends.

Comment: data amount is huge. Is it good decision to pass data through Cookie?

Comment: @BappiDatta: size of cookies is restricted and also network transfer takes longer the bigger the amount is. Therefore rather no cookie. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**If both the pages are in different domains -**

From the MVC controller action make a [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the webform page, in the Request body of HttpWebRequest send the data you want to send. On the retrieving side you can use Request object and read the data.

**If both the pages are in same domain -**

You can use Cache (server side), Cookies (client side), Hiddenfields (for Form Post from MVC controller to ASPX Page)

Comment: can you please give me an example or give me any link.